# SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault, during runtime execution on arm (CortexA9)

Tags: c, go, arm, cgo, clips

#### What I do

I'm building go application that should be run on CortexA9 CPU and uses 3 different C/C++ shared libraries (I use C wrapper to call C++ code), when calling one of them (Clips rules engine http://www.clipsrules.net/) I accidentally get `SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault`, the library itself is quite old and well tested, also the same code works well on amd64  arch. The place where error occurs looks quite random, if I rewrite code to avoid the specific code lines, it will occur in the middle of an other function.

##### How I build lib

I use `arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi` toolchain and `arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` as C compiler, so is built with this CFLAGS: `-Wall -std=c99 -O3 -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard --sysroot=${some path}`

If I build Clips as standalone binary (with this toolchain) and run some rules on it, it works well.

##### How I build golang app

I build app on docker golang:1.16-buster, where my toolchanin is placed

`go clean && env CGO_CFLAGS="-march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -mtune=cortex-a9 --sysroot={soem path}" CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS="linux" GOARM=7 GOARCH=arm go build --tags=with_libs,arm -o ./out/$app_name .`
CC is set to `arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`

To add library to project I have `arm.go` file:

```golang
// +build arm

package clips

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L../../libs/arm -lclips -lm -Wl,-rpath -Wl,../libs/arm
import "C"
```

#### What did you expect to see?

I expect to see no unexpected signals.

#### What did you see instead?

While app is running, when I perform cgo calls from so library I get this (from gdb):
`Thread 1 "myapp-arm" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.`

gdb: backtrace:

```
    #0  0x76d6fa6c in PrintTemplateFact (theEnv=0x4c8b90, logicalName=0x76d79184 "FactPPForm", theFact=0x4c6dd8, seperateLines=0, ignoreDefaults=0) at /myapp/clips_source/tmpltutl.c:387
    #1  0x76cbfa70 in PrintFact (theEnv=0x4c8b90, logicalName=0x76d79184 "FactPPForm", factPtr=0x4c6dd8, seperateLines=0, ignoreDefaults=0) at /myapp/clips_source/factmngr.c:445
    #2  0x76cbf704 in PrintFactWithIdentifier (theEnv=0x4c8b90, logicalName=0x76d79184 "FactPPForm", factPtr=0x4c6dd8) at /myapp/clips_source/factmngr.c:328
    #3  0x76cc1950 in EnvGetFactPPForm (theEnv=0x4c8b90, buffer=0x535290 "f--1    (attribute (id ) (comment ) (code ) (path", bufferLength=1023, theFact=0x4c6dd8) at /myapp/clips_source/factmngr.c:1590
    #4  0x002661e8 in _cgo_4cadad88d928_Cfunc_EnvGetFactPPForm ()
    #5  0x000823d8 in runtime.asmcgocall () at /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:596
    #6  0x00a16050 in ?? ()
```

gdb disas:

```
...
   0x76d6fa3c <+616>:   mov r2, r1
   0x76d6fa40 <+620>:   ldr r1, [r11, #-60] ; 0xffffffc4
   0x76d6fa44 <+624>:   ldr r0, [r11, #-56] ; 0xffffffc8
   0x76d6fa48 <+628>:   bl  0x76c68edc <PrintAtom@plt>
   0x76d6fa4c <+632>:   b   0x76d6fad0 <PrintTemplateFact+764>
   0x76d6fa50 <+636>:   ldr r3, [r11, #-8]
   0x76d6fa54 <+640>:   lsl r3, r3, #3
   0x76d6fa58 <+644>:   ldr r2, [r11, #-24] ; 0xffffffe8
   0x76d6fa5c <+648>:   add r3, r2, r3
   0x76d6fa60 <+652>:   ldr r3, [r3, #4]
   0x76d6fa64 <+656>:   str r3, [r11, #-28] ; 0xffffffe4
   0x76d6fa68 <+660>:   ldr r3, [r11, #-28] ; 0xffffffe4
=> 0x76d6fa6c <+664>:   ldr r3, [r3, #4]
   0x76d6fa70 <+668>:   cmp r3, #0
   0x76d6fa74 <+672>:   ble 0x76d6fad0 <PrintTemplateFact+764>
   0x76d6fa78 <+676>:   ldr r3, [pc, #232]  ; 0x76d6fb68 <PrintTemplateFact+916>
   0x76d6fa7c <+680>:   add r3, pc, r3
   0x76d6fa80 <+684>:   mov r2, r3
   0x76d6fa84 <+688>:   ldr r1, [r11, #-60] ; 0xffffffc4
   0x76d6fa88 <+692>:   ldr r0, [r11, #-56] ; 0xffffffc8
   0x76d6fa8c <+696>:   bl  0x76c68c3c <EnvPrintRouter@plt>
   0x76d6fa90 <+700>:   ldr r3, [r11, #-8]
...
```

#### EDIT:

I can even get SEGFAULT with this code:

```golang
func SelfHealthCheck(deftemplate string) {
    env := C.CreateEnvironment()

    // Create deftemplate
    cconstruct := C.CString(deftemplate)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cconstruct))
    if C.EnvBuild(env, cconstruct) != 1 {
        log.Println("error")
        return
    }

    // Obtain pointer on it
    cname := C.CString("attribute")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cname))
    tplptr := C.EnvFindDeftemplate(env, cname)
    if tplptr == nil {
        log.Println("error")
        return
    }

    // Create fact
    factptr := C.EnvCreateFact(env, tplptr)

    // print it
    var bufsize C.size_t = 1024
    buf := (*C.char)(C.malloc(C.sizeof_char * bufsize))
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(buf))
    C.EnvGetFactPPForm(env, buf, bufsize-1, unsafe.Pointer(factptr))
    log.Infoln(C.GoString(buf))
}
```

Comment: Looks like `theFact->theProposition` was null (or invalid).

Comment: Sounds like a plain old undefined behavior bug. Post this `PrintTemplateFact` source.

Comment: It's not null, it refers invalid memory address, and the same code works on amd64 arch.

Comment: @Lundin method is quite big, and it works when Clips is compiled as stabdalone binary. But anyway: https://pastebin.com/NRfiGHTp

Comment: btw, clips sources are available here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.31/ but as I mention it's old and well tested project.

Comment: Ok so probably you are initializing the 3rd parameter passed to `PrintTemplateFact` incorrectly.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads of execution on the CLIPS environment you've created? You can only safely have one thread executing at a time for an environment. For example, if one thread is executing rules and another thread is asynchronously asserting facts, you would need to synchronize the two so that thread executing rules pauses between rule firings to allow the other thread to assert facts.

Comment: @GaryRiley Actually I get error on very simple example, see last edit on my question.

Comment: @KirillSolokhov Is 1024 large enough to hold the string representation of the fact being created? I'm not familiar with the wrapper you're using. Does the error also occur if you use the C API directly rather than using the wrapper?

Comment: @GaryRiley looks like this code, does not work on arm if I don't call `EnvAssignFactSlotDefaults` while works on amd64. anyway thank you for your time!